# Exclude dates in scheduleExpression

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, javabeans

I have an EJB timer with timing specified in a scheduleExpression. Is there a way to exclude a list of dates in the schedule, i.e.:

Do not run on weekends and some list of other dates?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to execute it on all days not week-ends : you can set

```
scheduleExpression.dayOfWeek("Mon-Fri")
```

To exclude a discrete list of specific dates with just one schedule expression would be more tricky in my opinion. Maybe you could use more than one and use the start and end fields.

More details here : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html